# Why currying with obj doesn't work?

Tags: f#

Can you explain why one works but not the other?

**Given**

```
//fu : unit -> unit
let fu() = ();;
```

**This works**

```
//exec : (unit -> unit) -> int -> unit
let exec (f:(unit -> unit)) (data:int) = f();;

//this works, and p : int -> unit
let p = exec fu;;
```

And it works for other types of `data` such as `string`, `long`, etc.

**This doesn't work**

```
//exec : (unit -> unit) -> obj -> unit
let exec (f:(unit -> unit)) (data:obj) = f();;

let p = exec fu;;
```

and I get the following error:

> error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'p' has been inferred to have generic type
>       val p : ('_a -> unit)
>   Either make the arguments to 'p' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

Notice the only difference between these cases is the type of the `data` parameter. 
When it is `obj` or `System.Object` or `'a` - it doesn't work.

Another thing is that if `data` has type `obj` then the following happens:

```
//Data type is obj
let exec (f:(unit -> unit)) (data:obj) = f();;

//specifying parameters explicitly
let p x = exec fu x;;
```

Now `p` has the signature of `'a -> unit`, not `obj -> unit`.

So the question is: why the "shortcuted" currying doesn't work when `data` is `obj` or `'a` and why the type of `p` is `'a -> unit` when `data` was `obj`?

Answer (score 3):

So I think the problem is that F# appears to be generalizing at the wrong point (from your point of view):

Here is a version of your code that at first glance shouldn't typecheck:

```
let exec (f:unit -> unit)  (data:obj) = f();;
let p:int -> unit = exec (fun () -> ());;
```

This seems weird as `int <> obj`.

Also, here is an even simpler example which shows your behaviour (from the spec with modifications)

```
type Base() =
    member b.X = 1
type Derived(i : int) =
    inherit Base()
    member d.Y = i
let exec (f:unit -> unit)  (data:Base) = f();;
let p = exec (fun () -> ());;
```

which produces a value restriction error.

This makes it more clear that as F# inserts an implicit upcast before the function calls, the code is valid where it is a function, but once you make it an explicit value, this cast can't be used.

If you want your code to compile, you need to move the location of the upcast by adding a type annotation:

```
let exec (f:unit -> unit)  (data:obj) = f()
let p:obj -> unit = exec (fun () -> ());;
```

Comment: So I assume it is a bug or a limitation of an F# type inference? Because to me the compiler has enough information to generalize to something that can work, say, don't change the `data` parameter type at all.

Comment: @AlexeyRaga - I think that it may be best to view this as a limitation of F# inference.